# Help - camper van electrics

Tags: battery, accessories, inverter

I have bought a 24v inverter (I know) for my camper van that I will be powering by 2x12v batteries in a series.... my question is can I run the rest of the 12v appliances lights etc off one of the 12v batteries at the same time or does this have to be a separate battery hook up?

Comment: should not be a problem, but the one driving the 12 V stuff will discharge more quickly.

Comment: thank you for quick response... will that cause any issues one discharging quicker than the other?

Comment: If you charge them at 12V separately, and cycle them it will be ok.

Comment: That's a big "if".

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not connect your 12 volt loads to one of the inverter batteries, as that battery will be discharged more than the battery used only by the inverter.  When recharging the batteries, the inverter-only battery will be over-charged before the shared battery is fully charged.

The inverter-only battery may be damaged by excessive charging, while the shared battery will progressively get a lower and lower maximum state of charge.

Comment: This would only be true if you used a 24 V charging system to charge the two batteries in series. If you (switch) reconnect the batteries and charge at 12 V this would not be a problem,

Comment: Yes - two separate 12 volt chargers, one on each battery, could also work, but I'd still be concerned that the shared battery would be much more deeply discharged than the inverter-only one.